# Access Virtual PC Website from Host Browser

Tags: iis, desktop

I have Virtual PC 2007 running Windows XP. I can access a website setup on the Virtual machine from a browser in the Virtual machine. How do I setup the virtual machine so I can access the website from a browser on the host machine. The host machine is also running WinXP.

Both host and virtual machine can ping each other via IP and computer name.

TIA
rams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they can ping each other then you've done most, if not all, the things you need to do.

From the host's browser, you should be able to type the IP address of the guest into the browser address bar and bring the site up. Does this not work?

Comment: unfortunately using the IP address or the host name does not work.

Comment: So short and useless answer.

Comment: @QMaster It's not one of my best, though it sounds like I led rams in the direction of what they needed at least. Would be a comment these days for sure, but why do you feel the need to bring this up on an *8 year old* post?

Comment: Time the users spends to search for solutions for their problems is matter. Any answer may exist but that is amazing if very short and unclear answer was accepted as correct solution.

Comment: @QMaster the answer was accepted *by the OP* so it can't have been that unhelpful to them. I actually would agree that this is a poor quality answer by more modern standards, I just don't see why you've chosen this as the battle to fight. Downvote and move on, that's what you're supposed to do if you don't like my answer. Or flag it for the mods as "not an answer". Either way, I've spent enough time on this.

Comment: I Can't downvote your answer even I want to do because of my low reputation :) I didn't choose to fight, believe me. Just I try to found a solution to access my web application developed in VMware from the host and read more and more solutions without any success because of short and unclear answers like this. I'm sorry if annoying you.

Answer (score 0):

Like Robert said above, if you can ping both machines from one another, most of the things needed should be setup.

The key here is the availability of the port 80. My corporate supplied Virtual PC image has Windows Firewall turned off and I had to turn it on, and allow HTTP access.

You can use Advanced port scanner to scan for open ports on your virtual machines and if 80 is not open, configure the windows firewall on the virtual machine to allow port 80 access.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, followed advice to turn on 'bridged' connection in the network tab for VMWare Fusion, could ping between host and guest but still couldn't connect browse to my iis site.

The solution for me was to go to Windows Firewall settings in the Control Panel on the guest OS, click 'Allow a program or feature through Windows Firewall' and check World Wide Web Services (HTTP)

I can now browse through ip and via hostname (when listed in the hosts file on the host OS)